# Google Maps API V3 - Element onClick - Center Map / Open InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been playing around with the Google Maps API lately, and I have links that perform a JS function. This JS function partially works, on click it centers the map to the pin coords, but I also want it to show the infowindow; Everything works except opening the infowindow. Any help would be amazing! the code is a little cluttered with PHP / WP functions.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    var map;
    var infowindow;
    var marker;

    function initialize() {
        var styles = [
            {
                stylers: [
                    { hue: "#c09c3d" },
                ]
            },{
                featureType: "road",
                elementType: "geometry",
                stylers: [
                    { lightness: 50 },
                    { visibility: "simplified" }
                ]
            }
         ];

         infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
             maxWidth: 275
         });

        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo $centerCoords; ?>),
            styles: styles,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), mapOptions);

        var image = '<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/icon_marker.png';

        var locations = [
             <?php
                // LOOP ARGUMENTS
                $args = array( 'post_type' => 'cbd_dealers', 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' ); // -1 Shows ALL Posts
                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

                // CUSTOM CONTENT
                $dealerStreetAddress = get_post_meta($post->ID,"dealerStreetAddress",true);
                $dealerCity = get_post_meta($post->ID,"dealerCity",true);
                $dealerState = get_post_meta($post->ID,"dealerState",true);
                $dealerZipCode = get_post_meta($post->ID,"dealerZipCode",true);
                $dealerCoords = get_post_meta($post->ID,"dealerCoords",true);
                $dealerPhoneNumber = get_post_meta($post->ID,"dealerPhoneNumber",true);
                $dealerLink = get_post_meta($post->ID,"dealerLink",true);
            ?>

            {
                latlng : new google.maps.LatLng<?php echo $dealerCoords; ?>,

                info: '<style>a{color:#000000 !important;}a:hover{color:#DCB54F !important;}</style><strong style="line-height:25px;display:block;width:230px;"><?php the_title();  ?></strong><?php echo $dealerStreetAddress; ?><br /><?php echo $dealerCity; ?>, <?php echo $dealerState; ?>&nbsp;<?php echo $dealerZipCode; ?><br /><?php echo $dealerPhoneNumber; ?><br /><a href="<?php echo $dealerLink; ?>" style="line-height:25px;display:block;width:230px;" target="_blank">View Website</a>'
            },

          <?php /* END WHILE AND RESET QUERY */ endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>

              ];

            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: locations[i].latlng,
                    icon: image,
                    map: map
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {   
                  return function() {

                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i].info);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                  }
                })(marker, i));
            }

    }
    function loadScript() {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' + 'callback=initialize';
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        }
     function set_map_center(lat, lng) {

              var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
              infowindow.open(map,marker);

              map.setCenter(myLatLng);
              map.setZoom(12);
              infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }

    window.onload = loadScript;
</script>
```

Comment: You want all the infowindow opened on all the markers or only on a specific one? Something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_linktomarker.html?marker=1)?

Comment: I see you declare a function set_map_center(lat, lng) but you never use it.  Can you just call map.setCenter(marker.position); inside the function where you add the 'click' listener to the marker?

Comment: You need to bind the click on the link to the click on the marker. So in your `onClick` event of the link, trigger the click of the `marker` it corresponds to. That way the click listener on the `marker` will handle the `infowindow` opening. (Hope that makes some sense?)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Suvi's comment, i understand better.

First off, you will need to store all of your markers in an array when you create them.  Then in your set_map_center function, you can scan through the markers to find a matching Lat/Lng, and then trigger that marker's click event.

To trigger the marker click event:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');
```

Here is how I check for a lat/lng match

```
function set_map_center(lat, lng){
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
    for(var i=0;i<markers.length;i++){
        if(markers[i].position.equals(pos))
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[i], 'click');

    }
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uWPe9/5)

Comment: Hey, that's almost it - but you can run into cases when the lat/lng are the same. @geocodezip actually handles this nicely in his demo by dynamically creating the links as he creates the markers in the `createMarker` function. He's also got the markers in a global array, and each time a link and a marker is created the link is given an array ID to pass to the click function - which triggers the click on the correct marker in the array.

Comment: I'm not the best when it comes to javascript.. How would I create the array? I've played around with it a bit and can't seem to get it to function

Comment: To create an array: `markerArray = []`. To add items into an array dynamically: `markerArray.push(item)`. Hope that helps?